# track a link a user followed to reach my website

Tags: php, url, hyperlink, web-crawler

I would like to track the link that a user followed to reach my website just like google analytic does?

Comment: I think you've answered the question in the question.

Comment: "referrer" is what you must google if you want to know where the user comes from.

Comment: you can try with `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

Comment: http://in.php.net/results.php?q=%24_SERVER[%27HTTP_REFERER%27]&l=en&p=all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    if (preg_match('/^https?\:\/\/(www\.)?\mywebsite\.(com|org|net)$/im', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
        // from your website //
    } else {
        // from other website //
    }
} else {
    // direct typing in browser //
}
```

Above regular expression match only

```
http://website.com
https://website.com
https://www.website.com
http://www.website.com
```

Write your own Regex. Hope this helps you. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Unless you have a relationship with the other website and they allow you to add tracking detail to the link, you cannot reliably get this information. You can get referrer information from the HTTP request headers but they are not completely reliable.

Comment: reliably perhaps not, but it's more than what you may ever need with referrers.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the [$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) value, it will contain the URL the user clicked in order to reach your page.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the 'HTTP_REFERER' attribute of the $_SERVER array but they're not 100% reliable

as John Conde said